# Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, address=0x0) - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, button

My app has a problem that if I click a button to open a window, close the new window, and click the button again, it crashes and xcode says:

> `Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, address=0x0)`

Comment: a lot of things could cause `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` . Show us codes.

Comment: I kinda went the quick way around and connected buttons to windows in interface builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, so if anyone has this problem, just go into your xib, click on your windows, and uncheck release when closed

Answer (score 0):

Your button is attached to a method, that much is *certain*.

That method is being called on the second push, *that's logical too.*

So an object pointer that is alive in the first push is being *assigned nil after the first push*.

My guess, without any code from you to help give any further insight, your window is already created before pushing the button.  Later, when you close the window, the pre-existing object is assigned nil.  Then you try opening it again, you reference it without checking it being nil.

That's my guess of an answer, without any code to see.  Feel free to accept this answer, it's perfectly reasonable, without seeing any code. :)